# Which HTML tag is suitable for inline-block style? div or span?

Tags: html, css

The `<div>` tag is used to group block elements.

The `<span>` tag is used to group inline elements.

Which HTML tag is suitable to group inline-block elements? `<div>` or `<span>` or anything else? Why?

Comment: It depends on what kind of tags your  `inline-block` elements are. An inline-by-default element like `span` that contains a block-by-default element like `div` is always **not semantic**, no matter what `style` you give them.

Comment: @Itay, `div` elements are not allowed within `span` elements. Neither element has implicit semantics either.

Comment: @zzzzBov Couldn't understand what you are saying. Anyway, I did write that `div`s aren't allowed inside `span`s.

Comment: @Itay, you wrote "An inline-by-default element like span that contains a block-by-default element like div is always not semantic" which implies that `div` elements may be contained within `span` elements (semantic != valid). What I said was that a `div` within a `span` is invalid, and that neither `span` nor `div` has any semantics associated with the element by default unless explicitly added via some other method, such as aria-role attributes.

Comment: Okay sorry, I guess I mixed up `semantic` with `valid`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial assumption that:

> The `<div>` tag is used to group block elements.
>   The `<span>` tag is used to group inline elements.

is incorrect.

[`div` elements are defined as follows in the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-div-element):

> The `div` element has no special meaning at all. It represents its children. It can be used with the class, lang, and title attributes to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.

[`span` elements are defined as follows](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-span-element):

> The `span` element doesn't mean anything on its own, but can be useful when used together with the global attributes, e.g. class, lang, or dir. It represents its children.

The important difference is that the `div` element has a content model of [flow content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#flow-content-1), while the `span` element has a content model of [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#phrasing-content-1). A parent element's content model is what defines which child elements the parent may contain.

It does not matter whether the child element is `display: inline-block`, if the child element does not belong to the appropriate content model, it may not be validly placed within the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML spec, `<span>` is an inline element and `<div>` is a block element. Now that can be changed using the display **CSS property** but there is one issue: in terms of **HTML validation**, you can't put block elements inside inline elements so:

```
<span>...<div>foo</div>...</span>
```

is not strictly valid even if you change the  to inline or inline-block.

So, if your element is inline or **inline-block** use a `<span>`. If it's a **block level** element, use a `<div>`.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Because of browser comparability issues with `inline-block` (IE6,IE7) and the need to apply the fix of `*display:inline; zoom:1;` to get them to wotk on `block` elements..

I would go with `<span>`, because even IE6 % IE7 support `inline-block` when its applied to `inline` elements. (the fix is needed for `block` elements like `<div>`)

Answer (score 0):

Both are generic wrappers, but considering that [`span`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/span.html#span) is inline by default and [`div`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/div.html#div) is block by default, `div` would be more appropiate to hold elements with `inline-block` display CSS rule.